# select2 plugin and json format rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-select2

I am using this gem for autocomplete feature:

https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails and select2.

This is my action:

```
def autocomplete_subject
   @messages = Message.where(:by_the_system => nil).page(params[:page]).per(params[:page_limit])
    messages = Array.new
    @messages.each do |m|
      element = Hash.new
      element[:id] = m.id
      element[:text] = [m.subject].join(' ')
      messages << element
    end
   results = Hash.new
   results[:results] = messages
   respond_to do |format| 
     format.json { 
      render :json => {
        :results => results,
        :total => @messages.count,
     } 
    }
  end
 end
```

This is my javascript:

```
function messageFormatSelection(message) {
  return message.subject;
}

$("#search_boxes #subject").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        multiple: true,
        width: "300px;",
        ajax: {
            url: "/admin/messages/autocomplete_subject_nil.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (term, page) { // page is the one-based page number tracked by Select2
                return {
                    subject: term, //search term
                    page_limit: 5, // page size
                    page: page, // page number
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 5) < data.total;                
              return {results: data.results, more: more};
            }
        },
        formatSelection: messageFormatSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
   });
```

This is my json view:

```
{"results":{"results":[{"id":"50b4f5c01d41c811fb000014","text":"Microfunc con id: 50ae41011d41c86ad8000004"},{"id":"50b4f8d31d41c811fb000026","text":"Re: Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4fcf61d41c811fb00002e","text":"Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4fe531d41c811fb000032","text":"Re: Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4ff431d41c811fb000038","text":"Re: Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4f5d71d41c811fb000017","text":"Re: Microfunc con id: 50ae41011d41c86ad8000004"},{"id":"50b4f8231d41c811fb000024","text":"Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4fa921d41c811fb000028","text":"Re: Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4fee41d41c811fb000034","text":"Re: Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4ff291d41c811fb000036","text":"Pedido con id: 50b4f6041d41c811fb000018"},{"id":"50b4ffd71d41c811fb00003a","text":"mira os poneis deacuerdo o que"},{"id":"50b5013d1d41c811fb00004b","text":"Re: Microfunc con id: 50ae41011d41c86ad8000004"},{"id":"50b51ccb1d41c811fb000061","text":"mensaje enviado desde el panel de administraci\u00f3n"},{"id":"50b51e0c1d41c811fb000063","text":"Re: mensaje enviado desde el panel de administraci\u00f3n"},{"id":"50b51e461d41c811fb000065","text":"Microfunc con id: 50ae3b321d41c849c500000b"},{"id":"50b51e611d41c811fb000068","text":"Re: Microfunc con id: 50ae3b321d41c849c500000b"},{"id":"50b61b831d41c80b5d000004","text":"Re: mira os poneis deacuerdo o que"},{"id":"50b897a41d41c83613000034","text":"Microfunc con id: 50ae3b321d41c849c500000b"}]},"total":18}
```

**I want to get the results sorted by the search and use infinite scroll feature, but it is not working properly.**

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What attribute(s) do you want to sort by?

Comment: I want sort `text` attribute, and I need use infinite scroll each 5 results!. Thank you!

Comment: See my answer - but I'm curious why you have this code: `element[:text] = [m.subject].join(' ')` which seems equivalent to just: `element[:text] = m.subject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting needs to be done server side, not on the client since the client doesn't have access to all elements at load time.  From your code it appears that `text` is equivalent to your Message `subject`.  If so, you can simply modify this line:

```
@messages = Message.where(:by_the_system => nil).
  page(params[:page]).per(params[:page_limit])
```

to include a sort order:

```
@messages = Message.where(:by_the_system => nil).
  order(:subject).
  page(params[:page]).per(params[:page_limit])
```

Your response should include the current page, and whether this is the last page:

```
respond_to do |format| 
 format.json { 
  render :json => {
    :results => results,
    :total => @messages.count,
    :page => params[:page].to_i,
    :last_page => @messages.last_page
 } 
}
```

You also need to modify your ajax request to update the *page* variable instead of an unused 'more' offset:

```
results: function (data, page) {
          page = data.page + 1;
          if (data.last_page == data.page){ 
            // do something to disable searching as list is now exhausted
          }
          return {results: data.results};
        }
```